# How to do shortcut bat files to choose the next login OS - dual boot 7 and 8

Tags: windows, multi-boot, batch

I have dual boot Win 7 Pro 64-bit and Win 8 Pro 64-bit on a Dell Optiplex 7010 MT.

How can I write two batch files on the desktop of EACH OS to tell it to reboot either into Win 7 or into Win 8.  (Four batch files total, two on each desktop.)

Need it because I frequently remote into this machine and have no way of rebooting efficiently into the desired OS.

I could use in each OS:
System Properties - Startup and Recovery - Settings - System Startup - Default Operating System
but it just takes too long to go there, make the setting and then do restart.

I'd like some batch files that do all of that for me.

Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a script-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 1):

```
bcdedit /default {<OS GUID>}
shutdown /f /r
```